# Convergence of a series !!

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like prove that the following series is convergent
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left\{\,
\left[\,\left(\, s + n^{2}\, \right)^{1/2}-n\, \right]^{2} - x\, \right\} \,  \,  {\left[\, \left(\, s + n^{2}\, \right)^{1/2}\, -\, n\, \right]^{5/2} \over n^{2}},
$$
where $s>0$, $x<0$

Comment: Use limit comparison with $\sum 1/n^{9/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[ \left(((s+n^2)^{1/2}-n)^{2}-x\right) \,  \,  \frac{((s+n^2)^{1/2}-n)^{5/2}}{n^2}\right]\; n^{9/2} = (-x)\;2^{-5/2}\;s^{5/2}
$$
Since $\sum 1/n^{9/2}$ converges, our series also converges.

Answer (score 1):

If $$a_n=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+s}-n\right)^{5/2}
   \left(\left(\sqrt{n^2+s}-n\right)^2-x\right)}{n^2}$$ after factoring the $n$ and  using Taylor expansion for large $n$, we get an alternating series starting as $$a_n=-\frac{ \left(s^{5/2} x\right)}{4
   \sqrt{2}}\frac 1{n^{9/2}}+\frac{ s^{7/2} (2 s+5 x)}{32
   \sqrt{2}}\frac 1{n^{13/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{17/2}}\right)$$

May I add that I am not sure that the summation could start at $n=0$ as written in the post ?